# Icarus doesnt know how to parse localparam arrays?

Tags: arrays, verilog, iverilog

I am using v10 of Icarus Verilog, Windows 8.1 and am having troubles compiling 1D arrays like:

```
localparam [15:0] A[0:5]  = {
    0,
    10920, 
    21840,
    32760,
    43680,
    54600
};
```

or 2D array like:

```
localparam [1:0] B[0:5][0:2] = {
    {2'b00, 2'b10, 2'b01},
    {2'b10, 2'b00, 2'b01},
    {2'b10, 2'b01, 2'b00},
    {2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10},
    {2'b01, 2'b00, 2'b10},
    {2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b00}
};
```

When I try to compile this using iverilog inside command prompt like: `iverilog -o tb.vvp ".v files here"` I get the following errors:

```
tb.v:39: syntax error
tb.v:39: error: syntax error localparam list.
tb.v:54: syntax error
tb.v:54: error: syntax error localparam list.
```

Lines 39 and 54 are lines where upper two arrays are located.

What is wrong and how can I fix this ridicilous error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog does not support unpacked arrayed parameters/localparams; SystemVerilog does. See:

- [How to initialize parameterized array parameter using loop/generate in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32546844/1959732)
- [How to initialize parameter array in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26300881/1959732)

Icarus Verilog (iverilog) has limited SystemVerilog support. [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/) currently includes Icarus Verilog 0.10.0 11/23/14, which does not support unpacked arrayed parameters with SystemVerilog enabled. You can try with the latest version of Icarus. Enable SystemVerilog by changing your file extinctions from `.v` to `.sv`, you may need to add the `-g2012` compile option.

If that doesn't work, you will need to convert the array into a large vector. You can slice the array with the `+:` operator (Added in Verilog 2001 and supported with Icarus Verilog. See [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)). Or change to another simulator that supports SystemVerilog.